# Sending GPS Location to server

Tags: gps

Is it possible to send my current location on iPhone or Android to the server so that others can view my current location?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an email solution would be a workaround?

[GPSLogger for Android](https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger) app can automatically send an email with gpx or kml file to a specified address.

[image]

You could either push those emails to specified users or process the files on your server.

Answer (score 2):

In Android there are many apps that will locate your location.

If you want to build your own app here is one way to do it.

Using GPS and Google Maps in Android - **android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** is the key

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.learn2develop.GPS">
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".GPS" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Full source code:
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39239/1954

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, with a dozen answers. The short one is: Yes.

But, I do not think you are as interested in the IF, as you are in the HOW.

I'm not going to get into details, but outline some possibilities.

1. Use an existing service such as [Google Latitude](https://www.google.com/latitude/b/0)
2. Make an app (using GPS libraries for the phone) or a webpage using html5 geolocation, and push the location to a server.

Comment: Google Latitude has been retired in 2013 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Latitude)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could write an android app that uses the permission  (Just like Mapperz wrote), then sends this location to a database table on your server/hosting account. 
Then you can write a simple map page that looks up the most up to date location of yours in that table using AJAX in every x seconds/minutes/hours etc. and refreshes the map accordingly.
For the timing on the client side lookup function, you can use an example like `var location_lup = setInterval("your function()", 60000)`
In case you want to stop the app looking up your location from the table, you can write `clearInterval(location_lup);`

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to build a web app in html5 and communicate your position to a web server set up in node.js. If you put the communication with the server as web worker it wouldn't freeze up your phone very time it contacts the server. Use html5 localStorage to store coordinates if you loose contact with the server

Answer (score 0):

well you can find your location, and send that to server, so that other can find if and only if they have also installed the same application , there must be some permission also done to do this all.
use Google map you can have a look at the following website
http://www.trustingeeks.com/how-to-use-google-maps-v2-on-android-or-android-google-maps-api-v2-apps/